# Changing effects in compiz causes problems with the top panel

Tags: 11.04, compiz

Every time I change effects in Compiz my top bar gets screwed and I have to log out and log in again. Is it normal?

Can't install Simple Compiz Config Manager. Is it normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry you are encountering this problem (even if you didn't state exactly what the problem is ("get's screwed" does say much :)). (I assume you are running unity and 11.04 from what you describe).

In the future, all you need to do after changing you compiz settings, is:

- Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>

  - If you are running unity:

    - Type in `unity --replace` or simply `unity`
  - If you are running Ubuntu Classic Desktop:

    - Type in `compiz --replace`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

This will reload compiz and unity and should fix your problem as well. Hopefully the problem will be fixed in some soon_to_come bug fix updates.

---

*P.S.:*

<kbd>stuff</kbd> means <kbd>keyboard_key_to_press</kbd>

Comment: @Bojan: \o/ glad that solves it for you :)! Btw a little tip. When asking questions like this, please remember to include a little detail for us who have to answer (to make it easier for us to be accurate :P).

Comment: Just for more information on this issue, when I did <alt>f2 and "unity --replace" my UI froze up completely, except I could move the mouse pointer around.

Comment: It isn't a hudge issue but it definitely is a bug that will hopefully be resolved. Loging out and in again also isn't much of a hassle. @ Roland Ill keep that in mind next time ;).

Comment: @urge: That's totally abnormal O.o

Answer (score 0):

It happend for me to. And it also happened with ubuntu-tweak. Top panel becomes filled with a lot of colors or transparent... After restart and not using thoes 2 application it's ok.

Comment: As you can see above you don't have to restart, and you can still use the effects.